# php mysql max value ignore letters

Tags: php, mysql, string, max

I have a very simple data set like this:

```
Table: new_table
    -------------------
    id | some_string
    -------------------
    1    AB900
    2    AB200
    3    AB300
    4    400
    5    500
```

My goal is to select the highest number in a string, but and ignore the letters. So it is only the numbers that the query should select max of.

I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(a.some_string, 'AB', '') as stringRep, 
    MAX(stringRep) as newMax 
FROM 
    new_table a 
WHERE 
    stringRep 
BETWEEN 100 AND 500
```

But this returns that stringRep does not exists as a column - which I guess makes kind of sense. I would like it to return 900 (AB900) as a max number.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an alias defined in the SELECT anywhere but `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING` *(and the ability to do that is not universal across various SQL implementations, but is available in MySQL)*; you'll need to put the REPLACE inside the MAX... and probably wrap it in a `CAST(... AS SIGNED)` unless you want "9" > "10".

`MAX(CAST(REPLACE(a.some_string, 'AB', '') AS UNSIGNED))`

.....

`WHERE CAST(REPLACE(a.some_string, 'AB', '') AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 100 AND 500`

You could also just replace the WHERE with a HAVING, but many people consider a HAVING without a GROUP BY to be poor form, and I think some configurations of MySQL disallow it.